# Change plotly marker shape/symbol based on column value

Tags: plotly

Is there any straightforward way to change plotly marker shape/symbol attribute based on column values? It is quite easy for the color attribute.

Comment: Are you using Python, R or Javascript?

Comment: Python. I know one way to do it. Just set marker={symbol=df.value_column.astype('category').cat.codes}, but not sue if this is the best or easiest way.

Answer (score 6):

If you use [Plotly Express](https://plot.ly/python/plotly-express/) it’s just a matter of `px.scatter(df, x='colname1', y='colname2', symbol='colname3')`

Comment: What if we want to set the shape to a specific column value?